# change close button color in alert antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

hi this is my alert component using antd:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'antd';
import '../../styles/Alert.css'
export default function CustomAlert(props) {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div style={{    marginLeft: '1.5%' }}>
                {props.visible ? (
                    <Alert
                        message={props.message}
                        className={'alert'}
                        closable
                        afterClose={props.handleClose}
                    />
                ) : null}

            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    );
```

and the close button on alert is black but I want to change the color to another color for example red .
how should I style.

here is the current styles :

```
.alert{

    text-align: right ;
    direction: rtl ;
    position:  fixed;
    width: 96% ;

    height: 34px;
    margin: 0 0px 348px;
    padding: 0 7px 2px 6px;
    border-right: solid 4px #00bfa5;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-top-style: none;

    z-index: 100;

    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    background-color: rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.6);

}
```

Comment: You can override this css -> .ant-alert-close-icon - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-brahmagupta-e8ei7?file=/src/styles.css:60-80)

Comment: I don't know why but all the styles are applied except the color. I mean I copied your code and the background color is lightcoral but the color does not change